# Get Jquery startsWith count from each loop

Tags: jquery, loops

```
$(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function() {
   if(title_cont.toUpperCase().startsWith( alpha.toUpperCase() )){
      //code
   }
});
```

Here I want to get the count how many times `title_cont` started with `alpha`.
For example `title_cont` looped values are `vam`, `zam`, `cam`, `ver` and alpha is `v`.
So I want the output as 2.

Thanks

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: He needs to count how many coincidences are starting with a character (in this case `v`)

Comment: `title_cont` and `alpha` will have the save values for every iteration of the loop, no?

Comment: No alpha will be same but title_cont will be different

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable and sum +1 when a coincidence occurs:

```
var count = 0;
$(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function() {
  if(title_cont.toUpperCase().startsWith( alpha.toUpperCase() )){
    count++;
  }
});

console.log(count);
```

Note the compatibility is not wide.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility